# AngularJS Showing Busy icon when loading data

Tags: angularjs

i have created a small example which would show spinner when data will be loading. create directive for this because i can reuse it. problem is spinner loading all the time which is not right.

see the code and tell me where i made the mistake ?

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .directive('loading',   ['$http' ,function ($http)
 {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         template: '<div class="loading-spiner"><img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" /> </div>',
         link: function (scope, elm, attrs)
         {
             scope.isLoading = function () {
                 return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
             };

             scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v)
             {
                 if(v){
                     elm.show();
                 }else{
                     elm.hide();
                 }
             });
         }
     };
 }])
  .controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.loadData = function() {
        $scope.students = [];
        $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/x1rqt.json')
          .success(function(data) {
              $scope.students = data[0].students;
        });
      }

  });
```

jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/6L6p0bgd/

Comment: Possible Duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852676/angularjs-custom-directive-throwing-error

Comment: your directive is not working because hide() and show() functions are not implemented. if u have referred the code,  then the functions used there must be jquery functions. include jquery in ur project and try using jquery hide and show methods to implement your logic.

Comment: without jquery i solve it this way `if (v) {
                            elm.css('display', 'block');
                        } else {
                            elm.css('display', 'none');
                        }`

Comment: who gave me the negative marking and why?

Comment: @MonojitSarkar `.css()` is `jquery` property, Check this URL -
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=.css+in+jquery&oq=.css+in+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5671j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: And one more - https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    angular.module('myApp', [])
     
      .controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
          $scope.loadData = function() {
            $scope.students = [];
            $scope.loading=true;
            $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/x1rqt.json')
              .success(function(data) {
                  $scope.students = data[0].students;
                  $scope.loading=false;
            });
          }
          
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
      
        <h1>Loading spinner</h1>
        <div class="loading-spiner" ng-show="loading">
            <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" /> 
          </div>
        <div>
            <ul ng-repeat="student in students">
                <li>{{student.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="loadData()" class="btn btn-primary">Click for Load data</button>
    </body>
```

Hope it will help othrewise use isolation in your derective with = `scope`.

Comment: i just do not understand what you added in your code because you did not mention it.

Comment: do not use directve for simple logic make $scope.loading =true; and show hide your loader panel using ng-show="loading " in your html. its work

Comment: Look at following dive where i am going to show loader by using ng-show in your code,

 <div class="loading-spiner" ng-show="loading">
        <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" /> 
      </div>


and in your controller make use varivable by default false like  $scope.loading=false;

once you hit http request on server then make it true before get response so loader will get visible on you screen and as soon as you get response in a success or in finally block make this varible false  $scope.loading=false ; so loader div will get hide.

Comment: i post here my code just to know what was the fault in code for which spinner was showing always but you are telling me to follow different approach.